# Failed to get the number of elements in a table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, row

I have a problem to get the number of rows in a table, in an assert statement.
The following code works fine if running in debug, but fails if I run normally.

```
WebElement table = this.getDriver().findElement(By.className("table"));
int numOfRowBegining = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();

addTemplate();

table = this.getDriver().findElement(By.className("table"));
int numOfRowAfterAdding =  table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();
assertEquals(numOfRowBegining + 1, numOfRowAfterAdding);
```

addTemplate() adds an element to the table. The problem is with the value of numOfRowAfterAdding.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

> The following code works fine if running in debug.

This is a major clue. *In debug mode, you have a delay between the subsequent commands* allowing the page/elements to be loaded. When you run your code in a regular mode, you don't have that. In other words, this is a *timing issue* and you should look into using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) explicit waits.

What condition to wait for in your case is not completely clear. It would depend on what is happening inside `addTemplate()` function. If there is, say a spinner or a loading indicator, you may wait for it to become invisible via [`invisibilityOfElementLocated`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

Or, you can also write a *custom expected condition* to wait for the number of rows in the table to be greater than it had before.

Comment: thank you very much for your help , I will consider in the future

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the table to be loaded completely. First find an element which is related to table loading i.e. the element which will be visible only when the table is loaded completely and then use code snippet:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, MAXIMUM_TIME_EXPECTED_TO_WAIT);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(your_elem));
```